# Bootstrap5 - Carousel not sliding on iphone

Tags: iphone, mobile, carousel, transition, bootstrap-5

Is there a way to make the Bootstrap 5 carousel sliding on iphone? [Even on the official website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/), the carousel does not slide (on iphone) ?

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. In fact, I had checked the following option in the iphone settings to have less animations:
`Settings > Accessibility > Animation > Reduce animations`

By disabling this option the sliding effect works well.

Otherwise to bypass this setting you have to compile Bootstrap with the option
`$enable-reduced-motion: false;`

I hope this helps some of you